# AJAX form with e.preventDefault(); redirects to the PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, button

When I click the button to submit the form it sends me to the PHP file (Php/modify-recipes.php). I'm using AJAX with `e.preventDefault();`, but it doesn't seem to work. I have a similar form on my other page and it works fine. This one is a little bit different, the form is generated from another PHP file (it takes values from the database).

```
// AJAX (in HTML head tag)
<script>
    $(function () {

        $("#search-form").on('click', 'p.product', function(e){
            var product = $(this).attr('id');

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: 'Php/display-modify-recipes.php',
                data: { "id": product },
                success: function(response) {
                    $(".modify-recipes").html(response);
                    $(".search-results").html("");
                }
            });
        }

    )});

    $(function () {

        $('#add_recipes_form').on('click', '#add', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            
            let sendForm = true;
            $('.required').each(function(){
                if ($(this).val() == ''){
                    
                    $(this).addClass('error', 4000);
                    $('#placeholder-text').html("Fill in the form");
                    $('#placeholder-text').addClass('error');
                    $('#add').addClass('error', 4000);
                    
                    sendForm = false;
                    
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass('error');
                    $('#placeholder-text').removeClass('error');
                    $('#add').removeClass('error');
                }
            })
            
            $('.required2').each(function(){
                if ($(this).val() == ''){
                    
                    $('#placeholder-text').html("Fill in the form");
                    $('#placeholder-text').addClass('error');
                    $('#add').addClass('error');
                    $('#file_style').addClass('error');
                    
                    sendForm = false;
                } else {
                    $('#file_style').removeClass('error');
                    $('#placeholder-text').removeClass('error');
                    $('#add').removeClass('error');
                }
            })

            if (sendForm) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: 'Php/modify-recipes.php',
                    data: new FormData(this),
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function () {
                    },
                    error: function () {
                    }
                });
            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

```
// HTML
<form method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data' id="search-form" class="aaa">
  <input type="text" name="search-bar" class="search-bar" placeholder="Search">
  <div class="search-results"></div>                    
</form>
<div class="modify-recipes"></div>
```

```
// Php/display-modify-recipes.php
<?php
    
function display_mod_form(){
    
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cookbook");

    $product = $_POST["id"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = '$product'";
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $type = $row['type'];
        $difficulty = $row['difficulty'];
        $image = $row['image'];
    ?>

<form method="POST" action="Php/modify-recipes.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="add_recipes_form" class="add-form">
    
<input type="text" name="id" id="<?php echo $id ?>" value="<?php echo $id ?>" style="display:none;">

            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="required" maxlength="28" value='<?php echo $name ?>'>

            <label for="description">Desc.</label>
            <input type="text" name="description" id="description" class="required" maxlength="128" value='<?php echo $description ?>'>

            <label for="type">Type</label>
            <select name="type" class="required">
                <option value="dishes" <?php if($type == 'dishes') {echo "selected=selected"; } ?>>
                    Dishes
                </option>
                
                <option value="desserts" <?php if($type == 'desserts') {echo "selected=selected"; } ?>>
                    Desserts
                </option>
                
                <option value="snacks" <?php if($type == 'snacks') {echo "selected=selected"; } ?>>
                    Snacks
                </option>
                
                <option value="other" <?php if($type == 'other') {echo "selected=selected"; } ?>>
                    Other
                </option>
            </select>

            <label for="difficulty">Difficulty</label>
            <select name="difficulty" class="required">
                <option value="easy" <?php if($difficulty == 'easy') {echo "selected=selected"; } ?>>
                    Ease
                </option>
                <option value="moderate" <?php if($difficulty == 'moderate') {echo "selected=selected"; } ?>>
                    Moderate
                </option>
                <option value="hard" <?php if($difficulty == 'hard') {echo "selected=selected"; } ?>>
                    Hard
                </option>
            </select>

            <label for="image">Image (jpg, png)</label>
            <label for="upload_image" id="file_style">Choose image</label>
            <input type="file" style="display:none;" id="upload_image" name="image" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)" class="required2">

<div class="send-btn">
    <p id="placeholder-text"></p>
    <input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="Send">
    <div class="send-block"></div>
</div>

</form>
            
    <?php
    }

mysqli_close($con);
}

display_mod_form();

?>
```

```
// Php/modify-recipes.php
<?php 

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cookbook");
             
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $description = $_POST["description"];
    $type = $_POST["type"];
    $difficulty = $_POST["difficulty"];

    if ($_FILES['image']['name'] == ""){
        $sql_var = "SELECT image FROM product where id = '$id'";
        $var = mysqli_query($con,$sql_var);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($var)) {
            $image = $row['image']; 
        }
    } else {
        $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    }
    
    $sql = "
    UPDATE product SET 
        name = '$name', 
        description = '$description',
        type = '$type',
        difficulty = '$difficulty',
        image = '$image',
        last_mod_date = '$mod_date'
    WHERE id = '$id';
    ";

    $target = "../Uploads/".basename($image);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
    }

    $var = mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql); <!-- There are more queries -->

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

(Sorry for any mistakes, it's a shortened version)
There is a third ajax function and PHP file, but it's not important (simple search bar). I tried other things like `action=""`, no action at all, etc., but it didn't work.
How to fix this?

Edit: There is only one form (when you click on p.product it displays the form according to the data in the database). The problem occurs ONLY when I'm submitting the "add_recipes_form", there is no problem with the search box. Please don't mark this question as a duplicate of a 10 year old post that is irrelevant to my problem.

Comment: At a glance it looks like you are attaching the 'click' event to the form, not the submit button. Regardless, I think you would want to use the `onsubmit` event for the form, and then use `e.preventDefault()`. Something like `$("#search-form").on('submit', 'p.product', function(e){` instead.

Comment: @EssXTee He's delegating from the form to `p.product`, not attaching the handler to the form. But I don't see the `p.product` element. And `<p>` elements don't have a default action for the click event.

Comment: @Barmar True, but wouldn't you always want to apply `preventDefault()` to the submit event, rather than the click event of the submit button?

Comment: @EssXTee That's usually preferable, but either should work. The default action of the submit button is to trigger the form's submit.

Comment: If you're going to do that, you should remove the `p.product` argument: `$("#search-form").submit(function(e) { ... })`

Comment: As I wrote before, there is a third ajax and PHP script to create a search bar. It just displays a list of <p id="[$product]">, when you click it the form is displayed.

Comment: @Barmar I think that you misunderstood me. The form is being displayed correctly. There is an issue when I'm submitting the id="add_recipes_form" form. In addition to that, it replaces the data in the database as it should. The only issue is that it redirects me to the Php/modify-recipes.php file (blank page).

Comment: @Barmar I don't understand. There is only 1 form. I took the form tag out of the while loop too, it didn't work.

Comment: I suggest you confirm that the click handler is running, add `console.log("submitting  add_recipes_form")` to it. And check your console for other JS errors.

Comment: @Barmar I did that and used alert() too since the page is redirected and I can't see console logs. Either way, there was no result. There is only this error: GET http://localhost/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found) on the redirected (blank) page.

Comment: You should enable the "Preserve log" flag in the console so you don't lose the log when redirecting.

Comment: I suggest you do what @EssXTee suggested. Use a `submit` handler on the form rather than a `click` handler on the submit button. See if that fixes it.